# button shows old JSON value after pressing even though it changes in API once a minute

Tags: ios, swift

I have some strange trouble.
There is my button and connect to API :

```
 Alamofire.request("http://app", method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print("response",response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let success = json["success"].boolValue
            print("successs",success)
            if success == false{
                let error = json["error"].stringValue
                print(error)
            }else{
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data"][0] {
                    let name = subJson["user"]["name"].stringValue
                    self.nameCheck.append(name)

                }
               print("PresentTitle",self.nameCheck[0],"\(Date())")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

After pressing a button i see the same value each the time, but my value in API changes once in minute. But if you get out of this ViewController and go into it again, then a new value appears.

What do I need to do so that new values appear without leaving from ViewController?

Comment: Where does this code update the button? How is this code triggered?  Can you show more code in the context of where it is called/used?

Comment: Also, `if success == false` is a bit clunky. You should use `if success` and put the error handling into the `else` clause

Answer (score 0):

you can make a timer to call api every minute ,like this:

```
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(callApi), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You should set timer in the viewDidLoad() method.
Then make the function:

```
@objc func callApi() {
    // here you write your code 
}
```

Comment: Sorry ,so use real time database

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have to do a real-time application to handle this situation. A good alternative is the SignalR, based on WebSockets. They have a good .NET library and some swift pods, like this one:

https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR